# apache rewrite map redirect to 404

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, rewritemap

My Situation:

I implemented an apache Rewrite Map to redirect incoming requests based on a database

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteMap dbapp prg:/usr/local/somewhere/dbapp.rb
 RewriteRule ^/(pattern)$ ${dbapp:$1} [R]
```

So far everything works fine, but I want to decide in the dbapp.rb script weather to redirect or give the client a http-status-code-404. I could just deliver a local page that doesn't exist but that doesn't seem right. I also want this to be usable on any server, and redirecting to "localhost" is also not an option ;-)

Comment: May be its just me. But I am not quite getting the question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return `-`, which essentially means: 'no rewrite', but I don't know whether that's supported in a maps/`[R]` combination. Better may be to check with `RewriteCond ${dbapp:$1} !^$` or something that it doesn't contain an empty string.

Comment: returning "-" through the map just redirects to the relative url "-". However Checking the RewriteCondition works sort of. It just don't redirects at all. Mi final (workaround-)solution simply is a redirect to folder or file that just doesn't exist at all.